I keep getting NULL results
I have 2 tables i am working on.

dbo_Returns1 - which has  customer-id, return_date, returns, irder_id  and
dbo_Sales1 which has  customer_id, sales, sales_date, order_id

Question 1: What % of sales result in a return?
Heres my code that gave NULL result on SQLlite:
WITH SalesOrders AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        COUNT(*) AS total_orders
    FROM
        dbo_Sales1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
),
ReturnOrders AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        COUNT(*) AS total_returned_orders
    FROM
        dbo_Returns1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
)
SELECT
    ROUND((COUNT(DISTINCT r.order_id) * 100.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT s.order_id)), 2) AS return_percentage
FROM
    SalesOrders s
LEFT JOIN
    ReturnOrders r ON s.order_id = r.order_id
WHERE
    r.order_id IS NOT NULL;

Question 2: What % of returns are full returns?
WITH SalesTotal AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        SUM(sales) AS total_sales
    FROM
        dbo_Sales1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
),
ReturnsTotal AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        SUM(return_sale) AS total_returns
    FROM
        dbo_Returns1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
)
SELECT
    ROUND((COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SalesTotal)), 2) AS full_return_percentage
FROM
    SalesTotal s
JOIN
    ReturnsTotal r ON s.order_id = r.order_id
WHERE
    s.total_sales = r.total_returns;

This also gave a NULL result.
Question 3: What is the average return % amount (return % of original sale)?
WITH SalesTotal AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        SUM(sales) AS total_sales
    FROM
        dbo_Sales1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
),
ReturnsTotal AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        SUM(return_sale) AS total_returns
    FROM
        dbo_Returns1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
),
ReturnPercentages AS (
    SELECT
        s.order_id,
        (r.total_returns * 100.0 / s.total_sales) AS return_percentage
    FROM
        SalesTotal s
    JOIN
        ReturnsTotal r ON s.order_id = r.order_id
    WHERE
        s.total_sales > 0 -- to avoid division by zero
)
SELECT
    ROUND(AVG(return_percentage), 2) AS average_return_percentage
FROM
    ReturnPercentages;

Question 4: What % of returns occur within 7 days of the original sale?
Question 5: What is the average number of days for a return to occur?
I can seem to figure out how to solve these two.
I am new to SQL and will appreciate any help I can get for this project.

When you're using multiple CTEs and you're not seeing your expected results, it's always good to break down the individual queries, run each one of them separately, and first confirming that those individual queries are returning the results that you'd expect.  I'd suggest that as your first step in diagnosing your issues

Please edit the question and use the formatting tools. Capitals look ugly and is considered as shouting.

Question 1: What % of sales result in a return?
The issue might be in the way you handle the join and the COUNT. Here's a revised query:
WITH SalesOrders AS (
    SELECT
        order_id
    FROM
        dbo_Sales1
),
ReturnOrders AS (
    SELECT
        order_id
    FROM
        dbo_Returns1
)
SELECT
    ROUND((COUNT(DISTINCT r.order_id) * 100.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT s.order_id)), 2) AS return_percentage
FROM
    SalesOrders s
LEFT JOIN
    ReturnOrders r ON s.order_id = r.order_id
WHERE
    r.order_id IS NOT NULL;

Question 2: What % of returns are full returns?
Make sure the column names are correct and that the join condition is appropriate:

WITH SalesTotal AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        SUM(sales) AS total_sales
    FROM
        dbo_Sales1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
),
ReturnsTotal AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        SUM(returns) AS total_returns
    FROM
        dbo_Returns1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
)
SELECT
    ROUND((COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ReturnsTotal)), 2) AS full_return_percentage
FROM
    SalesTotal s
JOIN
    ReturnsTotal r ON s.order_id = r.order_id
WHERE
    s.total_sales = r.total_returns;

Question 3: What is the average return % amount (return % of original sale)?
Ensure that the columns and table names are correctly used:
WITH SalesTotal AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        SUM(sales) AS total_sales
    FROM
        dbo_Sales1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
),
ReturnsTotal AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        SUM(returns) AS total_returns
    FROM
        dbo_Returns1
    GROUP BY
        order_id
),
ReturnPercentages AS (
    SELECT
        s.order_id,
        (r.total_returns * 100.0 / s.total_sales) AS return_percentage
    FROM
        SalesTotal s
    JOIN
        ReturnsTotal r ON s.order_id = r.order_id
    WHERE
        s.total_sales > 0 -- to avoid division by zero
)
SELECT
    ROUND(AVG(return_percentage), 2) AS average_return_percentage
FROM
    ReturnPercentages;

Question 4: What % of returns occur within 7 days of the original sale?
Here's how to calculate the percentage of returns that occur within 7 days of the original sale:
WITH Sales AS (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        order_id,
        sales_date
    FROM
        dbo_Sales1
),
Returns AS (
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        order_id,
        return_date
    FROM
        dbo_Returns1
),
ReturnsWithin7Days AS (
    SELECT
        r.order_id
    FROM
        Sales s
    JOIN
        Returns r ON s.order_id = r.order_id
    WHERE
        julianday(r.return_date) - julianday(s.sales_date) <= 7
)
SELECT
    ROUND((COUNT(DISTINCT r.order_id) * 100.0 / COUNT(DISTINCT s.order_id)), 2) AS return_within_7_days_percentage
FROM
    Sales s
LEFT JOIN
    ReturnsWithin7Days r ON s.order_id = r.order_id
WHERE
    r.order_id IS NOT NULL;

Question 5: What is the average number of days for a return to occur?
Calculate the average number of days for a return:

WITH Sales AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        sales_date
    FROM
        dbo_Sales1
),
Returns AS (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        return_date
    FROM
        dbo_Returns1
),
ReturnDays AS (
    SELECT
        s.order_id,
        julianday(r.return_date) - julianday(s.sales_date) AS days_to_return
    FROM
        Sales s
    JOIN
        Returns r ON s.order_id = r.order_id
)
SELECT
    ROUND(AVG(days_to_return), 2) AS average_days_to_return
FROM
    ReturnDays;

